# element:first-child force reevaluate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `".hidden"` class, and I build DOM elements in realtime. So I get a simple code like:

```
...
    <div class="hidden">1</div>
    <div class="hidden">2</div>
    <div class="hidden">3</div>
...
```

My CSS definition is more than simple:

```
.hidden {
display: none;
}

.hidden:first-child {
display: block;
}
```

Everything is good everyone is happy. Now if I do something like: `$('.hidden:first-child').remove()` it removes, however the next element doesn't appear. It only seems to appear when I click on a DOM node in the developer console(**ctrl+shift+i in chrome**).

Any thoughts how to force the browser to evaluate the CSS rule?

**UPDATE**
This is a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/B8Nj2/). You will see "0" once buttons is clicked, there's no another number, and it should be "1", then "2" and so on.

**CONCLUSION:**
Strangely, however if I removed fadeOut(400) before remove() It works.

Comment: Can you reproduce a test case? I'm sure browsers already re-evaluate the CSS whenever the DOM changes.

Comment: @Sven Bieder: That doesn't matter since `:first-child` looks at an element, not its contents. The first `.hidden` element is still the first child (assuming all these elements have the class) - removing that, the second should then become the first.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/umt3q/ works fine

Comment: jAndy, thanks, but it doesn in my Chrome.

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, why not just explictly add `.next().show().end()` in the middle of your chain?

Comment: I have updated the question and included jsFiddle test case. On my Chrome 18.0.1025.152 it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using css pseudoclass :first-of-type instead of :first-child

Here is a working example on jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jukDU/3/

Comment: Strange why `:first-of-type` would work but not `:first-child` on Chrome, though... must be yet another one of its bugs.

Comment: @BoltClock's Unicorn I am really sure this is not a bug, however even the reprocuded jsFiddle does not work for me with first-child. Through my life first-child didn't fail me until now :)

Comment: I guess there must be something related with the DOM structure, and parent-child relationship.

Comment: that really looks like a bug in chrome/webkit then. Should work as expected with either selector. `:nth-child(1)` also works by the way.

Comment: If I removed fadeOut(400) before .remove() it works without a hassle. Maybe it's a bad practice to do so. I should bind animation end callback and then remove, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I would show the next item first then remove it.

```
$('.hidden:first-child').next().show();
$('.hidden:first-child').remove();
```

Comment: Nice answer, however seems a bit unnatural to em